# How to change and save the association of a model instance?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize for node.js. I define this relationship:

```
// 1:M - Platform table with Governance status table
dbSchema.Platform_governance.belongsTo(dbSchema.Governance_status, {foreignKey: 'platform_status'});
dbSchema.Governance_status.hasMany(dbSchema.Platform_governance, {foreignKey: 'platform_status'});
```

So that means I have a table called platform_governance which has a foreign key that points to a governance_status row. A user wants to change this foreign key to point to a different governance_status row.

So I want to first search that this governance_status row the user selected actually exists and is unique, and then make the foreign key point to it. This is what I currently have:

```
// first I select the platform_governance of which I want to change it's foreign key
dbSchema.Platform_governance.findById(5, {include: [dbSchema.Governance_status]}).then(result => {
  // Now I search for the user-requested governance_status
  dbSchema.Governance_status.findAll({where:{user_input}}).then(answer => {
    // I check that one and only one row was found:
    if (answer.length != 1 ) {
      console.log('error')
    } else {
      // Here I want to update the foreign key
      // I want and need to do it through the associated model, not the foreign key name
     result.set('governance_status', answer[0])
     result.save().then(result => console.log(result.get({plain:true}))).catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
```

The result.save() promise returns successfully and the object printed in console is correct, with the new governance_status correctly set. But if I go to the database NOTHING has changed. Nothing was really saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops just found the problem. When setting associations like this you shouldn't use the set() method. Instead, sequelize creates setters for each association. In my case I had to use setGovernance_status():

```
  // Update corresponding foreign keys
  result.setGovernance_status(answer[0])
```

If anyone finds anywhere in the documentation where this is documented I would appreciate :)